# Is it possible to call a Java method from gradle build script?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Basically I want to have in the build.gradle something like this:
version = Version.getVersion();

I have a class that contains the version of my application and I want to use that version when I create the jar in the manifest file.

How can be this achieved?

Comment: You want to get version from class that is located in a project being currently build? It that version hardcoded there?

Comment: Its kind of paradox to try to call a java class in the build script you try to compile/build this class. I would manage the version in the build script not a java class if this is not an option write it in a properties file and read it from gradle

Comment: Yes the version is hardcoded in a java class that is part of the project that is build.